# MemoryError when read a file larger than 2G

Tags: python

a single file with size greater then 2G.
I call `open(f, "rb").read()`
MemoryError.
I call `open(f, "rb").read(1<<30)`
OK

How can I eliminate the 2G limit? I have enough memory -- 16G

Comment: For programs running in 32bit, the process have limited (accessible) working memory of 2GB. You cannot overcome this limitation unless you run in 64bit.

Comment: Why would you need to read the whole 2GB file in one go? Can't you process it in bite-size chunks instead? Using the file as an iterator gives you data line by line, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters just to test the efficiency of reading disk. but get MemoryError for file >2G, therefor I changed it to 1G (1<<31).

Comment: @Itaypk Yes, my OS is win7 64bit, but python is 32bit.

Answer (score 4):

What about using Memory Mapped Files ([`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html))? There's a good example in the [documentation on python.org](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html). It is adapted below.

```
with open(f, "rb") as fi:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(fi.fileno(), 0)

    # Do stuff

    mm.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

As @itaypk said in the comments, 32bit executables are limited to 2GB of accessible ram (2^31).  In order to utilize additional RAM, you would need to run a 64bit version of Python.

Depending on what you need to do with the file, you may not need to read it entirely. You can step through it:

```
with open('huge_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       print line # print one line at a time
```

The above loop will not exhaust all available memory on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your file may be only 2GB, the overhead of reading it in may result in far more than 2GB of memory used.

Comment: Why would you assume this?